# How to convert hhmmss.ff format into datetime with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How can I convert the following time format:

hhmmss.ff (like 110241.22 is 11:02:41.22)

into the date/time format with pandas?

I tries to use `pandas.to_datetime()` but it fails to do the conversion. Here is an example:

```
hhmmss='110241.22'
pd.to_datetime(hhmmss)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) on this method yet? You will need to use the `format` parameter of this method.

Comment: I had read the documentation but I could not understand how the format was working. Now I do, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the `format` you want to convert the time to. Here's a helpful resource for figuring out what each [symbol means](http://strftime.org/). Here's [Pandas documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
pd.to_datetime(df['column_name'], format = '%H%M%S.%f')
```